# Would you please correct my translation?

Tags: translation, reading-comprehension

would you please help me out figuring out this couple of lines? This is a couple of sentences in a conversation between two rivals, who meet on the evening before a match while one of them is training. One of them comes from the former champion school, while the other (the one training) comes from the runner-up school. The lines are the following:

(Player 1): グラウンドがすぐ近くにあるホテルとは。。。IH 準優勝様は違うね

(Player 2): IH優勝校がどの口で言う

BTW, IH stands for inter high schools tournament. My translation is

(Player 1): The field is just next to the hotel.... maybe it's different for the runners-up to the inter high tournament , eh?

(Player 2): What is the Inter High champion school saying? ((Or, are the Inter High champion schools ones to talk?))

But both lines sounds odd to me, and I'm afraid I don't really understand them. Am I on the right track? In particular, the use of 違う has always been difficult to me. I'd really appreciate any help.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5):

This 違う means "different from others" or simply "special". IH準優勝様は違うね is a sarcasm, "Mr. runner-up is so different from the rest of us!" or "What a special treatment Mr. runner-up can receive!" Notice 準優勝**様**; this odd 様 indicates Player 1 is pretending to "admire" the runner-up as a joke.

IH優勝校がどの口で言う literally means "With what kind of mouth does a champion say it?", but it's basically just "How can a champion say that?" It's a natural response to the sarcastic remark of Player 1.

**EDIT:** どの口が言う (literally "which mouth says (it)") and どの口で言う (literally "with which mouth do [you] say (it)") is a set phrase meaning "How dare [you] say ～". The nuance is like [お前が言うな](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%8A%E5%89%8D%E3%81%8C%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA).

Comment: Thank you very much!! I couldn't have understood it without your help!